# on_click function assigned to Streamlit button runs before the click event in browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, button, streamlit

I am trying to run a script in streamlit button with `onclick=""` parameter. Problem is, the script start running before even button shows up on the browser. Any idea what maybe the mistake here?

```
import streamlit as st
from level_packs import create_packs
st.set_page_config(page_title="Main work", page_icon="")

st.markdown("# Main work")

st.button('Run script', on_click=create_packs())
```

Comment: How do you expect it to behave?

Comment: @Jamiu Shaibu I am expecting it to show up the button and after clicking on the button then start running the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialize a session state for the button and pass the function to an `if` statement.
Something like:

```py
runbtn = st.button('Run script')

if "runbtn_state" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.runbtn_state = False

if runbtn or st.session_state.runbtn_state:
   st.session_state.runbtn_state = True
   create_packs() # Your function
```

Comment: Thanks @Jamiu Shaibu, I already solved it. Your answer is working too :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried with below code and its working :)

```
import streamlit as st

from level_packs import create_packs as f

st.set_page_config(page_title="Main work", page_icon="")


st.markdown("# Main work")


def run_button():
    st.button('Run script', on_click=f)


run_button()
```

Comment: Yeah that is also another alternative.