# Why st.data_editor (when nested in st.button) disappear after changing a value?

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I will try to explain the title with a `.gif` :

[image]

Here is the code used :

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col": ["foo", "baz", "qux"]})

st.data_editor(df, key="OK")

if st.button("Show another df"):
    st.data_editor(df, key="KO")
```

Can you help me fix that, please ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a simpler way but @Jamiu S. [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73644869/21474411) solved my problem.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col": ["foo", "baz", "qux"]})

st.data_editor(df, key="OK")

runbtn = st.button("Show another df")

if "runbtn_state" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.runbtn_state = False

if runbtn or st.session_state.runbtn_state:
   st.session_state.runbtn_state = True
   st.data_editor(df, key="KO")
```

[image]